# vsftpd issue can't load RSA Certificate

Tags: vsftpd

This is my configuration for vsftpd:

```
anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list

write_enable=YES

local_umask=022

dirmessage_enable=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

xferlog_std_format=YES


chroot_local_user=YES

listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
tcp_wrappers=YES

# script to init pem:
# sudo mkdir -p /etc/ssl/private
# sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES

ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO

ssl_ciphers=HIGH

pasv_address=XXXXXXXXXXXXX 
#pasv_addr_resolve=NO

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=49152
pasv_max_port=49200
port_enable=YES

allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

I generated the RSA certificate with the command `sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem`

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What is the error you get?

Comment: yes sorry, ubuntu 22.04

Comment: You have `rsa_cert_file` and `rsa_private_key_file` the same file.

Comment: @Pilot6: 500 OOPS: SSL: cannot load RSA certificate

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate two different files: a key file and a certificate file.

You sent them to the same `/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem`

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key -out /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

Also update `vsftpd` config:

```
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key
```

Comment: I have still same error, I restared the vsftpd service: ```vsftpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT```

```

Comment: ```rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key```

Comment: also in the vsftpd.conf the certificate says: ```# sudo mkdir -p /etc/ssl/private
# sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

# We need to specify the location of our certificate
# and key files. We actually combined both pieces of
# information into a single file, so we will point
# both options to the same file:```